# Is there any way to encrypt the URL that is shown to the user in the browser to prevent link sharing?

Tags: python, django, url

I am looking for a way to encrypt the URL that is displayed to the user to prevent link sharing between users. This way I would be forcing the user to go through certain steps to access a certain path.

I am using the Django Framework and everything I have seen so far for encrypting the URL is in regards to hiding paths, however the URL is still valid and can be shared. In my case I want to show the user an invalid URL in the browser after the request with the valid URL has already been made.

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the URL a one-time use then you could use a framework like Django OTP to generate a one-time password so that the user can only use the link once and therefore cannot share it. The downside of this is that you need to generate new OTPs and links each time the actual user wants to do something. This might be fine for your use-case though:

https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/stable/